# Chrome extension is grey and popup won't show

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension is grey and the popup won't show. I am trying to get it to work on "https://scratch.mit.edu" and all subdomains, but it is grey on every site. The popup also doesn't show on any site.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
},  
"page_action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "19": "images/icon19.png",
        "38": "images/icon38.png"
      },
      "default_title": "Scratch theme loader",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },  
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "declarativeContent",
    "https://scratch.mit.edu/*",
    "https://pastebin.com/raw/*"
]
}
```

**background.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background operation for Scratch Themes</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {


      if (tab.url.indexOf('https://scratch.mit.edu') > -1) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
      } else {
        chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
      }
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Scratch Themes</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 357px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      img {
        align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <ul>
        <li>
            <img src = "images/S_Themes.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>Choose which theme you would like to use:</p>
            <form action="">
              <input type="radio" name="example" value="1"> Example 1<br>
              <input type="radio" name="example" value="2"> Example 2<br>
              <input type="radio" name="example" value="3"> Example 3
            </form>
        </li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put all the javascript code in js files, no scripting in html is allowed in background, popup and other extension pages, not even onclick attributes.

Comment: Thanks this worked great! I also had to change the permissions to add "tabs".

Comment: Note that such things as insufficient permissions, cross-origin issues etc. are usually present in similar ways. No visible errors, no alerts, no "undefined" troubles, just code that doesn't work at all -that's a good sign of permission troubles.